# Build AOSP for specific device

Tags: android, hardware, android-source

I want to build a custom ROM to a device (with AOSP) and need to know what I need to ask the vendors for. Do providers usually make drivers available in the format Google does? Anyone know what I need to ask for?

I have already spent a lot of time looking for answers here, at the xda-developers page, at the official AOSP page and all over the web, reading and watching videos. There's always something I don't understand. I would be very thankful if someone could help me on this one! I do not have any experience, yet, with embedded systems.

Thanks!

Comment: This is one of those situations where if you don't know what to ask, you are for the moment going to be limited to devices for which someone (probably the manufacturer) *already* offers a working AOSP build.  Once you've gained some experience with supported devices you can consider their unsupported but technically similar relatives... and maybe eventually doing an original port.   At a bare level you would need engineering information or driver source code for all peripherals you hope to use - ie, if you don't need the camera in your application then you *don't* need that information, etc.